# Express Singly-Linked List method in constant time: O(1)

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, big-o, time-complexity

I have written a method in a Singly-Linked list which inserts an object at the end of a list. It is written in linear time, O(n).

How would I perform this same task, but have the code written in constant time, O(1)?

**linear time code O(n):**

```
template <class Object>
void List<Object>::insert_back( const Object& data ) {
    ListNode<Object>* newnode = new ListNode<Object>( data, NULL );
    ListNode<Object>* lastNode = head;
    while (lastNode->getNext()!= NULL && lastNode->getNext()->getElement() != data )
        lastNode = lastNode->getNext();
    lastNode->setNext( newnode );

}
```

Comment: Keep a pointer to the last node in the list. Each time you add a new node to the end, update it to point to the new last node.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I'm having trouble visualizing this

Answer (score 2):

Normally, you have a head pointer to the list. In order to achieve what you want, you will need a tail pointer. Below is an attempt at giving a visual.

```
 [ A -> B -> C -> D ]
   |              |
 (head)         (tail)
```

And so your method would become (I don't know c++ so correct me if I'm wrong, but tail here is a field.)

```
void List<Object>::insert_back( const Object& data ) {
    ListNode<Object>* newnode = new ListNode<Object>( data, NULL );
    ListNode<Object>* lastNode = tail;
    lastNode->setNext( newnode );
    tail = newnode;
}
```

Comment: With a few changes, the function could be fixed to also work when the list is empty (`head` and `tail` are null).

Comment: @aschepler Yes, I forgot to include those cases. I guess I can leave it as an exercise for the reader.